# PouchDB/CouchDB Sequence Counter on Replicate

Tags: couchdb, pouchdb

I am *live* syncing a freshly minted pouchdb (3.3.1) to an established (iris) couchdb.

The initial replication happens successfully (*pause* event fired).

If I do `info()` on the Local, I get an update_seq of **362**. If I do `info()` on the remote, it shows an update_seq of **4201**.

I think this makes sense to me: the local db has no revisions - only the leaves (i.e. there are 362 leaves in the db) whereas the remote db sequence counter reflects all the historical changes that have been made since it was first created.

My question is: how can I programatically determine what the initial 'offset' in sequence counter is between the two databases? In particular I want to be able to measure the progress of the initial replication.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't really compare the seqs across two databases. However, you can do a `db.info()` on the remote database, grab the `update_seq`, and then compare that to the `last_seq` that is given to you in the `on('change')` event during replication. This will tell you how much progress you've made.

If you would like to see an example of this, the [NPM Browser](http://www.npm-browser.com/#/) does exactly this, to show the percent counter at the top. (It uses pouchdb-load as well, but the principle is the same, since the seqs are reported there as well.) The code is open-source, so feel free to check out how it works. :)

**Edit:** as pointed out in a comment,  if you are using `sync` rather than `replicate`, you need to check the `direction` parameter when reading `last_seq`. Also for Cloudant, you will need to split the string on `-` to get the integer seq.

Comment: for anyone else who might find this useful in the future: if you are using `sync` rather than `replicate`, you also need to check the **direction** parameter when reading  `last_seq`

Comment: also if you are using *cloudant* rather than *iriscouch*, note that `update_seq` and `last_seq` are not simple numbers (they contain the full revision string too)

Comment: simonberry: that's an interesting point. So does that mean that, with Cloudant/CouchDB 2.0, it's impossible to provide a "percent complete" view?

Comment: no... you can just do a `Number(info.change.last_seq.substring(0,info.change.last_seq.indexOf('-')))` to convert the seqence to a number you can work with ....

Comment: This seems to work fine for a pull. How about push? My last_seq is a number like 82 where as the update_seq is a string like 56-xxxxxx.

Comment: For a push, I had to do a db.info() on the local db. I found that the last_seq may be off by 1 from the update_seq even when the sync is complete. Hope that is correct.