# Number of pending changes to be replicated by PouchDB

Tags: angularjs, networking, ionic-framework, replication, pouchdb

My app uses PouchDB (and Ionic 1) to replicate it's data from a local DB to a server DB as soon as the network is available (through a live&retry replication).

I would like to display on the screen the number of changes waiting for replication (including 0 when everything has been replicated).

Is there some way to do that with PouchDB?

(If this is not feasible, a fallback solution would be to have a "dirty" flag, meaning that everything is replicated or not. Any idea for this?)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40857758/pouchdb-how-to-display-sync-progress-status) is helpful...

Comment: Thanks Phonolog, it helped! What I did is listen to the 'paused' event: when the err param is undefined, I set the status to "dirty (= needs replication)", otherwise to "pristine (=everything is sync'd)". However right after a change, it may take a few seconds before an attempt to sync is made by PouchDB, during which I report a "pristine" status while it is actually "dirty". Anyway I think that will do it for the moment, thx again

Answer (score 1):

Here is the way I did it (it's only the 'fallback' solution):

```
PouchDB.replicate(localDb, remoteDb, options).
  on('paused', function (info) {
    if (info == undefined) {
      // the replication has finished and is waiting for other changes
      $rootScope.syncStatus = "pristine";
    }
    else { // the are some pending changes to be replicated remotely
      $rootScope.syncStatus = "dirty";
    }
  })
```